# Context path from request or servlet context?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I inherited an application from another developer which always uses `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}`.  Is there a good reason to use this instead of `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`?  I can't think of how the two could be different.

Answer (score 0):

The API 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()
says

> The context path returned by ServletContext.getContextPath() should be considered as the prime or preferred context path of the application.